# Why are distinct multiprocessing.Value objects pointing to the same value?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In the following program, two processes are created. Each receives *it's own* `multiprocessing.Value` object. Somehow, the two processes still influence each other. Why?

I would expect the two processes to deadlock: The first process can increment the counter once (it's initially 0) but then should wait for it to be even again. The second process can never increment it, as it's 0 initially and never changes. Somehow, this deadlock does not happen, both processes continue to run.

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def inc_even(counter):
    print(f"inc_even started. {hash(counter)=}")
    while True:
        if counter.value % 2 == 0:
            counter.value += 1
            print("inc_even incremented counter")
        else:
            time.sleep(1)


def inc_odd(counter):
    print(f"inc_odd started. {hash(counter)=}")
    while True:
        if counter.value % 2 == 1:
            counter.value += 1
            print("inc_odd incremented counter")
        else:
            time.sleep(1)


multiprocessing.Process(
    target=inc_even,
    kwargs={
        "counter": multiprocessing.Value("i", 0),
    },
).start()
multiprocessing.Process(
    target=inc_odd,
    kwargs={
        "counter": multiprocessing.Value("i", 0),
    },
).start()
```

Output:

```plaintext
inc_even started. hash(counter)=8786024404161
inc_even incremented counter
inc_odd started. hash(counter)=8786024404157
inc_odd incremented counter
inc_even incremented counter
inc_odd incremented counter
...
```

Interestingly, if I change this to first create two variables that hold the two counters, the deadlock occurs:

```
counterA = multiprocessing.Value("i", 0)
counterB = multiprocessing.Value("i", 0)
multiprocessing.Process(
    target=inc_even,
    kwargs={
        "counter": counterA,
    },
).start()
multiprocessing.Process(
    target=inc_odd,
    kwargs={
        "counter": counterB,
    },
).start()
```

Output:

```plaintext
inc_even started. hash(counter)=8765172881357
inc_even incremented counter
inc_odd started. hash(counter)=8765172756097
```

Edit: If I replace the `multiprocessing.Value` object with some custom class, this does not happen:

```
class CustomCounter:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.value = 0
multiprocessing.Process(
    target=inc_even,
    kwargs={
        "counter": CustomCounter(),
    },
).start()
multiprocessing.Process(
    target=inc_odd,
    kwargs={
        "counter": CustomCounter(),
    },
).start()
```

This deadlocks as expected. So it must be caused by `multiprocessing.Value`, not just the multiprocessing in general.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @user2357112 Debian

Comment: Strange... this looks like the multiprocessing.Value object is getting reclaimed in the parent process, making its underlying memory available for reuse, but passing the value in the `kwargs` dict *should* extend its lifetime and prevent that from happening.

Comment: What exact Python version are you running?

Comment: So, I can reproduce on Mac if I use `multiprocessing.set_start_mode("fork")`, if I use the default spawn, I get a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @user2357112 I've tested it with python 3.11.4. I also ran it using 3.7.16 and 2.7.18 on an instance running Amazon Linux

Comment: interesting, this issue I found seems to be the same if I use the default spawn, where the value isn't referenced: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/94765

Comment: oh for - the docs *say* this should extend the lifetime, but then the code [deletes the references](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L125) that were supposed to be responsible for that. Friggin multiprocessing... one of the leakiest abstractions in the standard library, and a minefield of weird errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first Value is getting reclaimed in the parent process, causing the second Value to get allocated using the same shared memory.

---

According to the docs, your code *should* work. Under ["Explicitly pass resources to child processes"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines), the docs say

> Apart from making the code (potentially) compatible with Windows and the other start methods this also ensures that as long as the child process is still alive the object will not be garbage collected in the parent process. This might be important if some resource is freed when the object is garbage collected in the parent process.

Unfortunately, the docs don't match the implementation. The actual implementation [explicitly deletes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L125) the references that were supposed to prevent your Values from being reclaimed, inside [`BaseProcess.start`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L125):

```
del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs
```

This means that your code only works when you save references to the Value instances yourself, as you did in the version with the `counterA` and `counterB` variables.

The mismatch between docs and implementation should probably be reported on the CPython [issue tracker](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues).

Comment: Fascinating! Why does the code using my `CustomCounter` deadlock? I changed `hash(counter)` to `id(counter)` and both processes print the same value (as I would expect based on your explanation). Shouldn't this cause the same bug?

Comment: @Christopher so, a `multiprocessing.Value` is basically a proxy object over some shared memory buffer. The identity of the *python object* is actually a red-herring here, since they are *two seperate Python processes*, So even though they may have the same ID, they are in *different processes*, they are different objects.

Comment: I see, great! Thank you both! I will create a bug report in the CPython issue tracker.

Comment: The question I still have is why does the same underlying shared memory get re-used?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `multiprocessing` has its own internal [`Heap`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#L115) class that it uses to manage shared memory for `multiprocessing.Value` and a few related classes. When a `Value` is reclaimed in the parent, the shared memory is returned to the `Heap`, not to the OS. The `Heap` doesn't know whether any children still need the memory, so it can end up reusing memory that child processes are still working with.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, I was reading through that. certainly a lot of it is above my head, but I would have thought that it would have been zeroed here if retrieved again from the `Heap`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d2340ef25721b6a72d45d4508c672c4be38c67d3/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L50

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The second `Value` probably gets initialized before the first process gets scheduled for execution, so the memory gets zeroed twice before either child looks at it.

Comment: I've created an issue: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/110660